# How do I center this form inside a Jumbotron using Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Destiny 2 App</title>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style type="text/css">

        body {
            position: relative;
        }

        #email {
            width: 300px;
        }

        .jumbotron {
            text-align: center;
        }

        form {
            width: 700px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Destiny 2 Analyzer</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Download</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-3">Destiny 2 Analyzer</h1>
        <p class="lead">Delivering news and content about the new Bungie API pre-release Destiny 2</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>Sign up below to keep up to date on all news as it breaks!</p>

        <form class="form-inline"> //This form is what I want to center
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">@</div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>        

    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</body>
```

Please look at the form labeled, thanks! I've tried every possible way of centering it, but the elements inside the form never get centered! I appreciate any help. I am trying to finish up this project and this simple form is driving me absolutely insane.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `justify-content-center` class to your form to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To:

```
 <form class="form-inline">
```

Add:

```
 <form class="form-inline justify-content-center">
```